# running https server with google sdk

Tags: python

Is there any way to run https with with google python [sdk](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Python)?

```
google-cloud-sdk/bin/dev_appserver.py --host example.com ./out/app_engine/
```

The above command is used to run local [apprtc](https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc) server.
I have tried to change `apprtc/src/third_party/oauth2client/tools.py` and
`apprtc/src/third_party/oauth2client/old_run.py` but it didnot worked.
as I don't know python but tried a bit from looking other sites how to run https with python

line 165: tools.py

```
httpd = ClientRedirectServer((flags.auth_host_name, port),
                                 ClientRedirectHandler)
```

line 97: old_run

```
httpd = ClientRedirectServer((FLAGS.auth_host_name, port),
                                     ClientRedirectHandler)

httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (httpd.socket,
        keyfile="key.key",
        certfile='crt.crt', server_side=True)
```

as I don't know where it is actually running server where I can hook keys files.
Also I don't know which files to change this is just estimate that these files will be running server. after running above command I still get

```
INFO     2016-09-30 19:34:55,602 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://example.com:8080
```

Comment: Why do you need HTTPS?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid because chrome does not allow device apis(camera, jacks) without https domain

Comment: "localhost" is explicitly trusted, exactly for this purpose (development). Change the domain to localhost and it should work fine.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid i want to use this service over internet as localhost will not work.